# Excel: object variable or with block not set

Tags: excel, vba

Anyone know why the below code halts on `range_i.Copy` with error? This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803569/format-one-half-of-spreadsheet-red-and-fill-down-until-last-row/67804522?noredirect=1#comment119850572_67804522) but you don't need to review that question to know the answer to this one I don't think! :-) Thanks

> object variable or with block not set

```
Sub resort()
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, myrange As Range
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set range_i = Nothing
counter = 0

'Find last row
TrE = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Start loop assuming data starts in row 2 and 13 columns wide as in example
For Tr = 2 To TrE

    If Not myrange Is Nothing Then
        If ws.Cells(Tr, 13) = 0 Then
            Set myrange = Union(myrange, Range(ws.Cells(Tr, 1), ws.Cells(Tr, 13)))
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Else
        If ws.Cells(Tr, 13) = 0 Then
            Set myrange = Range(ws.Cells(Tr, 1), ws.Cells(Tr, 13))
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    End If

    If Not range_i Is Nothing Then
        If ws.Cells(Tr, 13) > 0 Then
            Set range_i = Union(range_i, Range(ws.Cells(Tr, 1), ws.Cells(Tr, 13)))
        End If
    Else
        If ws.Cells(Tr, 13) > 0 Then
            Set range_i = Range(ws.Cells(Tr, 1), ws.Cells(Tr, 13))
        End If
    End If

 Next Tr

'Create summary sheet

Sheets.Add.Name = "summary"
Set Tws = wb.Sheets("summary")

'Copy ranges into new sheet

offset_i = 2 + counter
myrange.Copy
Tws.Range("A2").PasteSpecial
range_i.Copy
Tws.Range(Cells(offset_i, 1), Cells(offset_i, 13)).PasteSpecial

'Now sort the pasted data for range_i

Tws.Range(Cells(offset_i, 1), Cells(TrE - 1, 13)).Sort key1:=Range("A:A"), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

'Copy the headers as well

ws.Range("A1:M1").Copy
Tws.Range("A1:M1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: This error can occur if range_i is nothing, did you step through the code to see if that's the case?

Comment: no, I must admit this isn't my strong suit, I will give this a go! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you may have figured this out already, here's for the sake of having an *answer* on a QA site...

As noted by Raymond in the comments: *"This error can occur if range_i is nothing..."* - And that is exactly why your error occurs.

`range_i` occurs six times in your code - three key points:

1. You `Set` it to `Nothing`.
2. The `If Not range_i Is Nothing Then` statement
3. Your problem line.

---

Here are some key learnings from these points;

### 1.

*You `Set` your variable to `Nothing`* but **you don't declare it!**

By having `range_i` as an undeclared variable, it's *implicitly* declared as a `Variant` data type - **not a range**.

You should include `Dim range_ i As Range` as part of your variable declarations - this will help avoid unexpected errors or issues like assigning something other than a range to the variable (Such as a value of the range rather than the range itself).

### 2.

`If Not range_i Is Nothing Then` is the same as saying `If range_i is Something Then` which I don't think is your intention?

### 3.

You are trying to copy some range intended to be set to a `Variant` variable that, as outlined above; you have never set because you first set it to `Nothing`, then prior to setting it to something you check if it's Not Nothing (Something) which it isn't.

Due to these issues you inevitably get the `Object variable or With block variable not set` Error.

---

You can read the documentation for this error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set).

Comment: Thanks so much, Samuel. I changed my "if" statements to If myrange Is Nothing Then + If Not range_i Is Nothing Then but now I get an invalid procedure call on Set myrange = Union(myrange, Range(ws.Cells(Tr, 1), ws.Cells(Tr, 13))) :-( hmmm

Comment: @daneee Although the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-5) isn't very clear on this error for all potential cases, it's being thrown because you are trying to use a `Range` variable that is set to `Nothing`. `Set myrange = Union(myrange, Range(ws.Cells(Tr, 1), ws.Cells(Tr, 13)))`. I tested the syntax of your line which threw the `Error 5` and then with 2 random `Range()` objects which worked fine.

Comment: @daneee if you aren't able to resolve the `Invalid Procedure Call Error 5` issue with the above comment, I'd suggest asking a new question specifically about that issue. If your issue is resolved per this question asked be sure to accept/vote per [what to do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)